# PHP result from a query with alias

Tags: php, postgresql

When i want to get a data from a SQL Query on my php system, i write something like

```
<?php echo $sqlresult['fieldfromresult'];?>
```

I was wondering if i can put a alias directely on this 'fieldfromresult'.

Example:

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.*, tb3.*
FROM tableone as tb1, tabletwo as tb2, tablethree as tb3 
WHERE
id = 1 and
tb1.idcolumn=tb2.idcolumn and
tb1.idcolumn=tb3.idcolumn
```

You see, it should be easy if i only specify what i want from every table (one, two or three), but i want all. The name of some of these columns are the same.
For example:
Tableone and Tablethree has a column named "description".

What i want in my PHP is something like a

```
<?php echo $sqlresult['tb1.description'];?>
```

if i use only `<?php echo $sqlresult['description'];?>` doesn't work.

Is there a way to make it without specify the columns I want on my query?

Comment: First of all `SELECT *` is common antipattern, it is better to specify all column names. Second using explicit `JOIN` is more readable.

Comment: `var_dump($sqlresult)` and you'll see exactly what the db created for field names.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the output to contain the table name as well as the column name you'd need to write your own output class/function to do this, referencing the table schema/meta data and creating your own array keys from this.

*Or*

You simpy name them by assosciation with `AS` such that:

```
SELECT tb1.description AS t1_description, tb2.description AS t2_description ... etc
```